# SharePoint List - View only assigned list rows

Tags: list, list-view

Is there an option in SharePoint 2010 where you can set it up so a user can only view the rows they were assigned based on a column in the data list?

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the [Me] variable](http://sharefort.blogspot.com.br/2008/03/using-me-filter-in-sharepoint.html) when you configure a filter on a view.
It's valid to People type columns.

It will not show the row when the AssignedTo column is targetting a Group. For that you need to go to a [more complex solution](http://www.makdeniz.com/how-to-filter-sharepoint-2010-tasks-which-are-assigned-to-you-and-the-group-your-are-member-of/) of using SharePoint designer to configure the filter for the list view.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.